# Reference request modules over a small category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, modules, free-modules, graded-modules

I am currently writing up one of my results where I am using modules over small $\mathbb{k}$-linear categories. I so far sadly did not find a proper introduction of them to refer the reader to and was hoping one of you could help.

Comment: What do you mean by "module" here? I'm only familiar with modules over monoidal categories.

Comment: a functor into the category of vector spaces, respectively for graded, into graded vector spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic reference is Mitchell's long [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870872900023) *Rings with Several Objects*.